# Gift Wrap Fields in BigCommerce API

Tags: api, bigcommerce

We have been trying to find the fields associated with Gift Wrapping in the API - and thus far have come up short. We are looking for the binary for selecting gift wrap, as well as the Gift Wrap type and comments. Likewise, we would love to have access to Gift card fields as well.

All we have found thus far is:

```
wrapping_cost_ex_tax, wrapping_cost_inc_tax, wrapping_cost_tax, wrapping_cost_tax_class_id
```

Could you please point us to the location of the Gift Wrap and Gift Note fields in the API?

Answer (score 1):

Gift wrapping properties can be defined on each of the "Order Products" in an order. The properties you list above from the Orders resource are calculated read-only values that represent the sum of any gift wrapping values for products in the order. See the [Order Product documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/order_product) for more info about defining gift wrapping properties.